# How to output/display modified text value using xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to display modified texts using xlst.

part of code.

**Case1:**

```
<tu>
<tuv xml:lang="en-us" changedate="20110216T070945Z"> 
<seg>
<ut>#  302 </ut>The gradient of the objective function cannot be
<ph x="1" type="inldel">!      </ph>computed at the starting point</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
```

**Case2**

```
<tuv xml:lang="zh-cn" changedate="20110216T070945Z"> 
<seg>
<ut>#  302 </ut>The gradient of the; objective function cannot be
<ph x="2" type="inldel">!      </ph>computed at the starting point</seg>
</tuv>
```

**Requests:**
1. when there are linebreaks\returns in text field, replace the returns with spaces and display\output the new string. 
In case1, The gradient of the objective function cannot be computed at the starting point.

1. when there are semi-colons, replace them with colons. 
   In case2, The gradient of the: objective function cannot be computed at the starting point.

**My current solution for case2:**

```
*<xsl:if test="tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text()">
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains(tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text(),';')">
   <xsl:text>translate(tuv[tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text(),';',':')</xsl:text>   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text()"/>   
</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>*
```

But the output doesn't show the returned vaule of Translate function, instead, it display "translate(tuv....)".

I'm new to xslt and suppose this is not a difficult question for experts:)
Can anybody help?
thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and for an extensive explanation. Do note that this solution is just an XPath one-liner expression. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  "<xsl:apply-templates select="seg/text()"/>"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="seg/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "translate(normalize-space(translate(.,'&#xA;;', ';:')),
               ';', ' '
               )
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (combination of your case 1 ad case2):

```
<tuv xml:lang="zh-cn" changedate="20110216T070945Z">
    <seg>
        <ut>#  302 </ut>The gradient of the; objective function cannot be
        <ph x="2" type="inldel">!      </ph>computed at the starting point
    </seg>
</tuv>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  "The gradient of the: objective function cannot be computed at the starting point "
```

**Explanation**:

1. In the innermost translate, in every text-node child of `seg` any ';' is replaced with ':' and any NL character is replaced with a ';'.
2. 1normalize-space()`is issued on the result of the innermost`translate()` and this strips off the leading and trailing white space, however the ';' characters are not touched -- this is the only reason we replaced the NL characters with ';' in step 1.
3. Finally, a `translate()` replaces any ';' with a space.

Comment: @Dimitre: And why not `translate(normalize-space(),';',':')`?

Comment: because `normalize-space() will destroy any NL characters, and they would not then be replaced as the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. I will try to figure out the how normalize-space() here makes a difference later.

Comment: @Dimitre: Also I'd like to clarify my first request: I need to replace linefeed\carriage return(if any) with a space, so that the whole sentence isn't split\wrapped into two lines. However, after _using translate(tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text(),'&#xA;',' ')_ the linefeed does become a space, but isn't replaced, meaning the sentence is still in two lines instead of 1 single line

Comment: @Jackie: What are you talking about??? You only need to perform the transformation from my answer on the XML document  -- you should get the same result I am getting.

Comment: @Dimitre:Sorry if I didn't state clearly. My discovery of the root problem has been: '<tuv xml:lang="zh-cn" changedate="20110216T070945Z"> <seg> <ut># 302 </ut>The gradient of the; objective function cannot be <ph x="2" type="inldel">! </ph>computed at the starting point </seg> </tuv>' 
1...<xsl:apply-templates select="seg/text()"/> will return all text value within Seg element
The gradient of the; objective function cannot be
computed at the starting point 
2..But <xsl:value-of select="seg/text()"/> will only return part of the text valueThe gradient of the; objective function cannot be

Comment: @Ignacio: although <xsl:value-of> returns the text of select attrbute, it will only return part of texts if there are nested tags inside the element. In this case, the result is **The gradient of the: objective function cannot be** Instead of expected one **The gradient of the; objective function cannot be _computed at the starting point_** As you can see, the texts in italic is truncated by <ph> tag. Any suggestions on this pls?

Comment: @Jackie: Just *use* my solution. It doesn't have the problems you are speaking about.

Comment: @Dimitre:Ops..It seems I didn't use your code properly...Now it works.Thanks a lot! You are my teacher in Xslt now.:)
Cheers

Comment: @Dimitre:Hi, could you help again with a succesive question?
'<tuv xml:lang="zh-cn" changedate="20110216T070945Z" changeid="Jackie"> 
<seg>
<ut>#  307 </ut>The optimization process needs than <ph x="3" type="index">%g</ph> iterations or <ph x="4" type="index">%g</ph> function calls</seg>
</tuv>'
What if I want to include text value within <ph> whose attribute is "index" only, while ignoring others, say texts in <ut>--
Expected result:

Comment: @Dimitre:Expected result:
The optimization process needs than **%g** iterations or **%g** function calls

Comment: I figured it out at last, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a XPath expression then you need to use a [`<xsl:value-of>`](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xsl_value_of.asp) element.

Comment: although <xsl:value-of> returns the text of select attrbute, it will only return part of texts if there are nested tags inside the element. In this case, the result is **The gradient of the: objective function cannot be** Instead of expected one **The gradient of the; objective function cannot be _computed at the starting point_** As you can see, the texts in italic is truncated by <ph> tag. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: That's in a separate text node; it must be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

To write the value of an expression to the output document you must use the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction, as in:

```
   <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="translate(tuv[tuv[@xml:lang='en-us']/seg/text(),';',':')"/></xsl:text>
```

Comment: **And `xsl:text` are not needed**